# ListView item's selection color with shading

Tags: android, listview, formatting

Is it possible to make `ListView` item's selection color show with shading (at the left for example).

I would like the list item at the left side to be lighter than on the right.

Comment: yes its possible use selector & use rectangle drawble do some R&D on them you will get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**pressed_gradient.xml:**(R.drawable.pressed_gradient)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#ffffff"
      android:centerColor="#ff0000"
      android:endColor="#000000"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**listview_selector.xml:**(R.drawable.listview_selector)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_gradient" />
</selector>
```

Now use in your xml like:

```
<ListView
  ...
  android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
  ...
/>
```